# Help moving text in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I am trying to move text in a previously save GIMP file, but when I click on the text, the whole image moves. I tried clicking on "Move active layer," but that didn't work. It seems the whole thing is one layer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think that it depends on the image, whether it's got layers or not, and where exactly you're clicking to try and move the text.  If everything is flattened into one single layer, then you can't.  If they aren't, then where you specifically click is critical to deciding whether you move the text or not, and that's a bit hard to help with here.  (Not offtopic necessarily, but still a tiny bit tricky to help with directly through Q/A)

Comment: If you look at `Windows > Dockable Dialogs` you should be able to display your layer pane -- that will help you figure out if the image is a single layer or multiple layers locked together.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of isolating and munipulating the image components.  The steps below is an easy guide to get started.

You can move the text layer independent of other components of your image with these steps.

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to bring up the Layers palette.
- Create a new Layer by clicking the **New Layer** icon at the bottom left of the Layer's window.  Select a solid color such as white for the **Layer Fill Type**.
- Drag the new layer to just beneath your text layer.
- Now lower the Opacity for your new layer so that you can see the image below your text layer.  You can do this by selecting the new layer and clicking the down button in the Opacity option.
- Now you can move your text layer, which will be easily selectable and is isolated away from the other parts of your image.

**Note**:

Using the Layer palette, you can easily identify whether the whole thing is one layer.  If that is the case, you can't move the text independently.  You'd have to find a copy of the image without the text, then add a text layer to that image, and work with that.  Then use the steps above to move the text independent of the image, as well as any other components of the file.

When saving the picture for distribution, it's often flattened, where you can't work on the individual components.  You would have to save a copy in Gimp's **xcf** format if you want to perform more editing of the components in the future.